# How to enable rotation on android on same activity?

Tags: android, layout, orientation

I am sorry, this question has been asked probably thousand times over, but I do not find the correct words how to ask this question.

I have an activity in android. When I turn the screen at 90 degrees, it looks like the current activity is completely destroyed and a new activity is initiated. Is that correct?

But if I have showed some data in one orientation, I want to show the exact same data in the other orientation? Is there some SIMPLE way to achieve this? That the activity just remains, but shows the layout with the SAME data from the SAME activity in the other orientation?

Comment: I think you need to add flag android:configChanges="orientation" inside your manifest file where you have defined your activity then inside your activity you need to override onConfigurationChange method then ...you need to define your logic what you want to show in orientation change

Comment: Can you provide an example? Why do I need to provide a logic? Its the same logic for ANY orientation...

Comment: If you want to show same orientation then just add flag in Android manifest file.

Comment: did not work. I added ` android:configChanges="orientation"` inside my activity, but when rotating the phone the activity was started new

Comment: could you please check if onConfigurationChanged method inside your activity is getting hit when you change the orientation of your phone?

Comment: I have solved my problem with the answers below; no need to implement/override a method `onConfigurationChanged`. You seem to have overread that I asked for a simple answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an easy way to save your time, if your project api level is upper than Android 3.2 (API level 13) add this code into your activity in manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Update: this also can help:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: It did work, I added the code in the wrong way. You did not provide a complete answer...

Answer (score 0):

Yes whenever an activity changes its rotation it is destroyed and recreated. and the same android uses same layout and roughly shows it into landscape mode.

You can make a new folder layout folders name layout-land.
layout-land may contain the same layout as in layout folder and the views can be tweeked  according to the landscape orientation requirments

Comment: you do not want the system to destroy and create the layout

Comment: It did work, I added the code in the wrong way. You did not provide a complete answer...

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to store all your information in savedInstanceState and restore it from there in onCreate(). Or use a Fragment with setRetainInstance(true) to store your information in.